# Is there any tool to automate test for installers (WiX or InstallShield)

Tags: unit-tests, continuous-integration

I was wondering if there is a way to define tests (something like unit test) for installers, specifically installers made in WiX and InstallShield.

Comment: You want to test the installers or you want to automate the installer process i.e. you don't need to click Next buttons any more and installer goes on & on.

Comment: I mean test the installers

Comment: You should try AutoIT for the same, as that is quite useful for such testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try TestComplete - I believe we use it to test installation here. Essentially you're just testing driving another windows application: if the environment can let you check registry entries and file content then so much the better (I don't work in TC at the moment and can't recall).

AutoIT could do it (I have used AutoIT a lot).

Comment: Both are good, AutoIT is free tool while TestComplete is a paid tool.